# Setting an options value as a style tag value using JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, inline-styles

I'm relatively new to jQuery, and I'm trying to get the option value to pull in as a font size value for the 'previewtext' class as inline styling.

My code works fine when it's a set value such as 8px, but when I want it as a variable, nothing happens.

```
<div class="textsize">
  <select class="form-control" name="fontSize">
      <option value="Size">Size</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
      <option value="16">16</option>
      <option value="18">18</option>
      etc...
  </select>
</div>

<div class="previewtext">
    the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("select.form-control").change(function(){
           var fontSize = $(this).val();
           $("div.previewtext").css({"font-size": "fontSize"px});
       });
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Jordan

Comment: try this `.css({"font-size": + fontSize +"px"});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("select.form-control").change(function(){
       var fontSize = $(this).val();
       $("div.previewtext").css({"font-size": fontSize+"px"});
   });
});
```

Hey Jordan, You can try again with this code.

Comment: This works but I would handle the string concatenation with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with string concatenation. One approach would be to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as shown below by changing:

```
....css({"font-size": "fontSize"px});
```

To:

```
....css({"font-size": `${fontSize}px`});
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("select.form-control").change(function(){
           var fontSize = $(this).val();
           $("div.previewtext").css({"font-size": `${fontSize}px`});
       });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textsize">
  <select class="form-control" name="fontSize">
      <option value="Size">Size</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
      <option value="16">16</option>
      <option value="18">18</option>
      etc...
  </select>
</div>

<div class="previewtext">
    the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
</div>
```